# How to deal with the two custom User model case in Django?

Tags: python, django

I make two models that inherit form `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`, names `User` and `AdminUser`.

But there are check identified errors when runserver, so I add :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "qiyun_admin_usermanage.User"
```

In my `settings.py`. the half error gone, but there still has the `qiyun_admin_usermanage.AdminUser`'s issue. I don't know whether I can set two custom models in the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, or there must only be one AUTH_USER_MODEL?

The traceback:

```
...
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
qiyun_admin_usermanage.AdminUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AdminUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AdminUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
qiyun_admin_usermanage.AdminUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AdminUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AdminUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
qiyun_admin_usermanage.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AdminUser.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'AdminUser.groups'.
qiyun_admin_usermanage.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AdminUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'AdminUser.user_permissions'.
```

Comment: You should probably try to create an `is_admin` field on your custom user model, or use groups to identify admins, instead of separate models.

Comment: Don't you think separate the normal user and admin user to two tables is better?

Comment: No, because they are both the same type of "thing" (users) and are different in their roles, not their attributes. Having two tables vastly complicates user management

Answer (score -1):

There could be only one of AUTH_USER_MODELs. If you want to separate users and admin, there is a snippet:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...
```

`PermissionsMixin` adds `is_superuser` column to your DB where permissions could be handled.

Comment: Doing the above when having two user models (as the OP asks) leads to the exact error of the question.